# Multipart Form Fields - Taxonomy Included

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, taxonomy-terms

I'm starting out a new project and I think I've come across something like it before but I can't think of the right search terms or something along those lines...

What I'd like is a module to add multiple fields to one node field. So like a text field and a taxonomy field where I can add multiple of both the taxonomy value and the combined row of the text and taxonomy fields.

I'm near certain I once dealt with something like this once before but I cannot think of it for the life of me.

I have found this: https://www.drupal.org/project/multifield but the problem with this is that it only allows for only ONE value in each field (aka ruining my chances for using it with taxonomy).

So if anyone's run into something similar or can think of a solution to my predicament I would be incredibly grateful for some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) module

Tutorial:
[Using Field Collection In Drupal 7](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1V1ofpgUw-Y)